# How do you reference a subappendix whilst still having pdf without a page break?

Tags: pdfpages, appendix

I'm having a few issues referencing a subappendix that has a pdf document in it. I'm currently using the current code below.

```
\includepdf[pages = 1, pagecommand=\subsection{IA Design Option 1 Engineering Drawing}, width = \linewidth]{Safety/Appendices/drawings/IA/IA_Design_Option_1_Drawing.pdf}
\label{appendix:IA_Design_1_engdrawing}
```

When I reference this in text with:

```
\ref{appendix:IA_Design_1_engdrawing}
```

instead of outputting 'D.1' it outputs just 'D'

I then changed the code to:

```
\subsection{IA Design Option 1 Engineering Drawing}
\label{appendix:IA_Design_1_engdrawing}
\includepdf[pages = 1, width = \linewidth]{Safety/Appendices/drawings/IA/IA_Design_Option_1_Drawing.pdf}
```

When I reference this in text with

```
\ref{appendix:IA_Design_1_engdrawing}
```

it now outputs 'D.1'. However not using pagecommand=\subsection within the includepdf function now means that my pdf document now appears on a brand new page.

I need to be able to have the pdf on the same page as the subsection heading and I need to reference them as subappendices D.1, D.2, D.3 etc. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Cheers

Damon

Comment: Based on the filename of your PDF, it seems to me that you are better off with using `\includegraphics`. To choose the right page use the `page` option, eg. `\includegraphics[page=3]{file.pdf}`. Concerning pdfpages: Please do not feed `\includepdf` with `\section`, `\subsection`, etc. commands. This will break sooner or later. It was not made to handle `\section` commands correctly.

Comment: \label usually stores the counter value from the previous \refstepcounter, as in \thefigure or \thesubsection,  IIRC, \includepdf does not preserve links or anchors in any way.